# How to push a target to a point page according to the request result from database?? (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, uialertview

It's bit of complicated but I will explain as possible as I can. I have 10 pages in a app with the unique variable id (1~10), each page has a uialertview with 2 buttons, yes/no. when I press yes, the app will send a data to a table in a database, and then retrieve a data from another table. The return data will contain a number ("3" for example). what I need to do is to push the button to the corresponding page after received a number from database. (ie: if I press yes, the app receive 3 from database, the button will push to id3 page)

what I have done:
I have settle done a database. The app is able to send a data to the database, and is also able to receive a data from database, however, I do not know how to push the button to the corresponding page after received a data.

I have a class in the yes button (.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RecommendationData.h"

@interface DataConnection : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *json;
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

@end
```

and(.m)

```
#import "DataConnection.h"

@implementation DataConnection

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex ==1) {
    [self sendData];
    [self receiveRecommendData];
}
}

-(void) sendData {
//send data//
RecommendationData *obj = [RecommendationData getInstance];

// create string contains url address for php file
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://phdprototype.tk/phpFile.php?maxValue=%@&collectionId=%@&level=%@&room=%@", obj.maxValue, obj.collectionId, obj.level, obj.room];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
}

-(void) receiveRecommendData {
 //receive data//
 NSURL *getResultUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phdprototype.tk/getResultData.php"];

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:getResultUrl];

 [self getData:data];
}

-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{

NSError *error;

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}

@end
```

Now, the received json data from database is

[{"max(id)":"3","recommendData":"8","room":"4F","level":"2"}]

in this case, the return ID is 8, so I would like to push the button to page8. In each page I have some codes in .m to set the unique id

```
RecommendationData *obj = [RecommendationData getInstance];
obj.collectionId=@"8";
```

can anyone provide some codes for me to complete this task?? Thanks